# MATCH_RECOGNIZE example in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-sql

I'm trying to make a CEP code using flink SQL, I would like to get started with this. It would be great if you could share a snippet of the code with me. MATCH_RECOGNIZE is what I want to use.

Example on :- https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/match_recognize.html

Thank You

Comment: you should share some code or the errors you are facing. People are more likely to offer meaningful help when they see you did some research...

Comment: I'll post a link

Comment: I've made a code but it doesn't use CEP library @TheFabio so it's meaningless to share, though i can if you want to have a look

Comment: MATCH_RECOGNIZE is just part of SQL. Take any of the MATCH_RECOGNIZE examples and insert them into one of the SQL in Scala examples (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sql.html#specifying-a-query).

Comment: Thanks @DavidAnderson I'm gonna try an example right now